# How to create a list of hex number in 8085 assembler?

Tags: 8085

I need to know how to create a list of number in 8085 assembler and store the list in successive memory location?

Answer (score 0):

Most assemblers will have a set of `define` statements and a way to specify different bases.

For example, the values zero, one and forty-two, along with a short nul-terminated string, may be created with something like:

```
some_vals:  db 0, 1, 2Ah, 'hello', 0
```

How *your* assembler does it is probably in the documentation somewhere. Without more specific details on which assembler you're using, this not much more help I can give.

Pseudo-ops like data definition (`db`, `dw`, `ds`), address specification (`org`) or label setting (`mylabel:`) do not generally form part of the processor documentation itself, rather they're a function of the assembler.

---

See, for example, chapter 4 of [this document](https://www.tramm.li/i8080/Intel%208080-8085%20Assembly%20Language%20Programming%201977%20Intel.pdf). I *particularly* love the fact that we used to buy these 200-page books for $3.95 whereas now you'll be shelling out a hundred bucks for a digital copy with no incremental cost of production :-)